# Expo BarcodeScanner works only the first time when I post data to my server on barcode scanned

Tags: react-native, expo

Expo BarcodeScanner works only the first time when I post data to my server on barcode scanned

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from "react-native";
import { BarCodeScanner } from "expo-barcode-scanner";
import { useSnapshot } from "valtio";
import phoneState from "../store/phoneState";
import { setqrText, setqrTextFlag } from "../store/phoneState";

export default function ScannerScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
  const [text, setText] = useState("Not yet scanned");
  const { qrText, qrTextFlag } = useSnapshot(phoneState);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("qrTexT: ", qrText);
  }, [qrText]);

  const askForCameraPermission = () => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === "granted");
    })();
  };

  // Request Camera Permission
  useEffect(() => {
    askForCameraPermission();
  }, []);

  // What happens when we scan the bar code
  const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    axios
      .post(`http://${localIP}:5000/api/qr/scanQr`, { data })
      .then((response) => {
        const { message } = response.data;
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        alert("ERR : ", e);
      });
  };

  // Check permissions and return the screens
  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{ margin: 10 }}>No access to camera</Text>
        <Button
          title={"Allow Camera"}
          onPress={() => askForCameraPermission()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  // Return the View
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.barcodebox}>
        <BarCodeScanner
          onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
          style={{ height: 400, width: 400 }}
        />
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.maintext}>{text}</Text>

      {scanned && (
        <Button
          title={"Go Back"}
          onPress={() => {
            setScanned(false);
            navigation.navigate("Home");
          }}
          color='tomato'
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

As you can see here, i want to send the scanned data to my server, in order to do that im using axios.post() after barcode scanned. At first try it works just fine, but afterwards it does not scan QR code. I tried to remove my axios.post() code and logged the scanned codes in the terminal, it is scanning all QR codes that i showed the camera as expected. How to change my code to prevent this happenning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about toggling some kind of waiting period while the data is actually getting sent to your server via the POST in a synchronous matter to stop the scan and then reactivate it right after?

I don't have the chance to test it on an actual device and replicate it to the precise bit but I hope you'll get the gist of it:

```
  // What happens when we scan the bar code
  const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    setScanned(true);
    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post(`http://${localIP}:5000/api/qr/scanQr`, { data })
        const { message } = response.data;
        // automatically restoring scanned to keep the ball rolling on the onBarCodeScanned callback
        setScanned(false);
      } catch (e) {
        alert("ERR : ", e);
      }
    })();
  };
```

The [Snack on the doc page](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/) also has such kind of behaviour and a warning notice is highlighted on the page itself:

> Note: Passing undefined to the onBarCodeScanned prop will result in no
> scanning. This can be used to effectively "pause" the scanner so that
> it doesn't continually scan even after data has been retrieved.

Comment: I wrote a code similar to your instance using async-await and it worked. Apparently async-await and axios's then() and catch() does not do the same thing. that was my mistake and now thanks to you problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';    
import {Alert } from 'react-native';
const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
```

Function: (Answer) Reload the Camera after alert is pressed. Alert usually ends any further functions, so connect further functions to the Alert call.

```
 const handleBarCodeScanned = () => {
    setScanned(true);
    
Alert.alert('QR Code Scanned', 'Press OK to Scan Again', [
  { text: 'OK', onPress: () => setScanned(false) },
  ]);
}
```

JSX:

```
    <BarCodeScanner
      onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
      style={styles.camera}
    />
```